# Derivative of a slope in a linear function in R

Tags: r, function, linear-regression, beta, derivative

When deriving the slope of a linear function (y = a + bx) it is stating the rate of change between x and y.  However, if I wanted to know the speed of the rate of change (essentially the second derivative) of the function with respect to a change in x, how exactly could this be done?

```
x = rbind(-0.13612333, -0.02364000,  0.08234000,  0.09092667,  0.02164000,
          -0.07784667, -0.10057333, -0.11222000, -0.07394333, -0.05615667)
y = rbind(0.013591, -0.045430, -0.013332, 0.010612, -0.013214,
         -0.05521, -0.022531, -0.013262, 0.087841, -0.0201230)
beta = cov(x, y) / var(x)
beta = -0.0218445
```

Comment: the second derivative of any linear function is zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the values of y are equally spaced, a classical approximation for the second derivative is obtained with

```
c(NA, y[seq_along(y) - 1]) - 2 * y + y[seq_along(y) + 1]
#[1]  NA  0.091119 -0.008154 -0.047770 -0.018170  0.074675 -0.023410  0.091834 -0.209067   NA
```

The result is given in arbitrary units since we don't have information about the units and the distances between subsequent values.

The common formulas for the calculation of finite-difference approximations of the first and second derivative can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference).

**Edit / addendum**

Here's another possibility that could be useful. One might fit the entire dataset to a quadratic function and determine the second derivative of the fit, instead of attempting to calculate the local value of the second derivative.

As clarified by the OP in the comments, the data is sequential in time `t`, where each value of `x` and `y` is recorded at equidistant time steps of one month. I assume that the values of `x` and `y` refer to the same month. Based on this assumption we can first eliminate the parameter `t` of the time sequences `x(t)` and `y(t)` and consider the functional dependence `y(x)`

```
y1 <- y[order(x)]  # reorder the data in ascending values of x
x1 <- x[order(x)]  # do the same for x
fit <- lm(y1 ~ poly(x1, 2, raw=TRUE)) # fit a second-order polynomial
```

This yields:

```
> fit$coefficients
#         (Intercept) poly(x1, 2, raw = TRUE)1 poly(x1, 2, raw = TRUE)2 
#         -0.01834248               0.03744701               1.76134780
```

The last coefficient is the second derivative of the fitted function. The result of the fit can be plotted with

```
plot(y1 ~ x1)
lines(fitted(fit) ~ x1, col=4)
```

[image]

Comment: The values of x and y are based on monthly changes in two given rates.  x = month( t + 1 ) - month( t ) and y = month( t + 1 ) - month( t ).  The units are in basis points...so x = 7.5, 7.6, 7.3, ... , and y = 3.5, 3.8, 4.5, ... ,.

Comment: @dxm078 If I understand you correctly the values are obtained at equal distance in time. That is good news because it means that both answers given so far seem to make sense. However, as I understood your OP, you seem to be interested in the beta, in other words, how y changes as a function of x. That is a different question than observing how x and y change in time. If you want to differentiate f=f(x); i.e. df/dx, or even d^2f/dx^2 instead of dy/dt or d^2y/dt^2 of y=y(t), and dx/dt of x=x(t), things can become quite more complicated.

Comment: That is correct sir, the distances are equal.  I have found the beta, essentially the differences in monthly rates between the two variables but now I would like to know the speed in which the variable y changes with x change.  Right now the equation reads as a simple linear function:  Y( t + 1 ) - Y( t ) = alpha + beta * (X( t + 1 ) - X( t )) + epsilon( t )

Comment: In that case I'm afraid that we are back to square one and that none of the answers give any insight. They show the acceleration of y in time, but not its dependence on x.

Comment: You would probably need to perform a local quadratic approximation around each value x[a] using three points, y(x[a-1]), y(x[a]), and y(x[a+1]). It can be done, but it's more complicated than what has been posted so far.

Comment: so essentially you're suggesting a 3 month moving average?

Comment: Not a moving average, just a parabolic approximation. Three points of the type y(x) can be used to define a parabola, i.e., a function of the type y=a+b*x+c*x**2. Once you have that parabola, you'll only need the coefficient c. The three points to use here are the values of three consecutive months for x and y.

Comment: If you are frequently confronted with similar questions in your work, you will find more accurate information on this topic, e.g., in [this book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387981840)

Comment: Great suggestion!  I didnt even know there was this kind of book out there

Answer (score 1):

The second derivative of the function `y= a + bx` is just 0. If you suspect there is a non-zero second derivative you will want to start with a different formula (for example, `y = a + b*x^2` - for which the second derivative would be `y'' = 2b`)

If you want to look at just how the y values change with respect to x, and how those changes change with respect to x, have a look at:

```
> diff(y)
           [,1]
 [1,] -0.059021
 [2,]  0.032098
 [3,]  0.023944
 [4,] -0.023826
 [5,] -0.041996
 [6,]  0.032679
 [7,]  0.009269
 [8,]  0.101103
 [9,] -0.107964
> diff(diff(y))
          [,1]
[1,]  0.091119
[2,] -0.008154
[3,] -0.047770
[4,] -0.018170
[5,]  0.074675
[6,] -0.023410
[7,]  0.091834
[8,] -0.209067
```

Comment: thank you!  And you helped me prove my point with a colleague

Comment: @RHertel `diff(y)/diff(x)` or something like that

Comment: @MichaelChirico Yes, I think that this would be much better for the first derivative. It remains a left-sided finite-difference approximation, which is far less accurate than the central difference approximation.

Comment: @RHertel sure, but i read this answer as a suggestion for eyeballing the answer... this should suffice for that purpose

Comment: from my example my x and y are stated as the absolute change in two given rates

Comment: @RHertel This is for **looking** at how the change in y with respect to x changes with respect to x. I didn't ever say this is how you calculate a second derivative.

Comment: the distance will vary these are abs changes of monthly rates.  In turn, the first x in my example is the difference between month(t+1) - month(t)

Comment: @SeñorO Fair enough, but you are saying that this shows *how the y values change with respect to x* although x enters nowhere in your answer

Comment: @RHertel Each value corresponds to the change between successive x values. Do I really have to explicitly say that? I'm suggesting a tool to use.

Comment: @SeñorO My apologies - the textbook result seems to yield the same output as yours with the given assumptions of equally spaced values.